# What are scenarios in which 'git stash' might fail?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am writing a script to check that my git repository submodules are 'clean' and checked out to the reference commit, before archiving the entire project for deployment.

I'm using python 2.7 with gitpython and if the submodule repository is dirty, I call stash with no aditional arguments to prevent the user from losing their changes. I have never faced a failure with that command, but for the sake of good practices I added a `try...except` clause to catch possible errors.

My problem is that I cannot come up with something that will cause `git stash` to fail in order to test the clause. I tried changing the ownership of one of the altered files to root, but stashing worked anyway.

Is there anything that might cause a simple stash operation to fail?

Comment: Your "permission denied" idea is a good one, you just need to push it further: change the owner of the entire `.git` tree, for instance, and make sure it's not accessible to the owner of the files. (Some users do this sort of foot-shooting thing to themselves now and then using a bad `sudo` for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at:

- the source: [git-stash.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-stash.sh)
- its tests: [`t/t3903-stash.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t3903-stash.sh)

That will give you an idea of the failure cases.

For instance, in an empty repo: ["You do not have the initial commit yet"](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-stash.sh#L90-L96)